# Logic Error with adding adView into the getView of my fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, adview

I found a logic error with my implementation of a Banner ad into the top of my getView. The issue is that the banner overlays over the first item of my listView. Everything else seems to work as expected. The following is my code.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.i("testing", "pos " + position);
           if (position == 0)  {
              if (convertView instanceof AdView) {
        // Don’t instantiate new AdView, reuse old one
                 return convertView;
         } else {

                Context mainActivity = getActivity();
                adView = new AdView(mainActivity);
                adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
                adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);    
        // Convert the default layout parameters so that they play nice with
        // ListView.

                float density = mainActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                int height = Math.round(AdSize.BANNER.getHeight() * density);
                AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                height);
                adView.setLayoutParams(params);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
                    .build();
                adView.loadAd(adRequest);
            return adView;
            }
           } else {
                convertView = getSherlockActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                      .inflate(R.layout.list_item_bxied,null);
            // Enter the view of this Bxied Attack
            // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
                // Enter the view of this Bxied Attack
                 Bxied c = (Bxied)getItem(position);
                 TextView titleTextView =
                     (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bxied_list_item_titleTextView);
                 titleTextView.setText(c.getTitle());
                 TextView dateTextView =
                     (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bxied_list_item_dateTextView);
                 dateTextView.setText(DateFormat.format("EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy  hh : mm a", c.getDate()).toString());
             CheckBox resolvedCheckBox =
                     (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bxied_list_item_resolvedCheckBox);
                 resolvedCheckBox.setChecked(c.isResolved());
            }
            return convertView;
         }     
      }
```

If you know the answer, I'd appreciate it if you can include some code that would fix this issue. the first item on the list should be in view under the banner Ad.

Here's the XML:

```
 <code>  
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

   <CheckBox 
     android:id="@+id/bxied_list_item_resolvedCheckBox"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 

     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:enabled="false"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:padding="2dp"
     /    
   <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/bxied_list_item_titleTextView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bxied_list_item_resolvedCheckBox" 
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:paddingLeft="4dp"
     android:paddingRight="4dp"
     android:text="@string/bxied_title"
     />
   <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/bxied_list_item_dateTextView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_below="@id/bxied_list_item_titleTextView" 
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bxied_list_item_resolvedCheckBox" 
     android:paddingLeft="4dp"
     android:paddingRight="4dp"
     android:top="4dp"
     android:text="Date"
     />

   </RelativeLayout>
</code>
```

Comment: What is the height of R.layout.list_item_bxied?  Try making it the same height as the banner ad to test.  Also try explicitly setting the height to e.g. 50dp, not the value retrieved from the Admob class.  At the very least log the value that actually gets set so you can see if it looks right...

Comment: I added my XML. In my research, it appears that I need to add delegate logic to distinguish between the ads and the other items on the list.

Comment: Not sure that's the common terminology, but I did find a relevant question that called their BaseAdapter 'delegate'.  If you haven't seen it, check the logic they use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229142/listview-with-ads

Comment: I tried adding this code into my ListFragment which is where the getview resides and I couldn;t get it to work. I had issues with adding the BaseAdapter.